# IIS 7.5 settings

Tags: iis

I have a site and, when I start from Visual Studio, fiddler says main page takes 2 seconds to load( with setting use local IIS server). When I start from IIS (browse same page), fiddler says 16 seconds.
Any idea what I should be looking for (every time before loading page I close all webdev processes and I hit IIS reset)?
Thank you

Comment: I think you might be comparing a "warmed-up running instance of Visual Studio Web Server" vs a cold-instance of IIS. In other words, when you start VS Web it will already load .NET, System.Web, etc, so the startup costs is samller. When you request it in iis you will create a new process, load the clr, load s.web, compile, etc, which is expected. What is the time for second request?

Comment: The time for the second request is very small, so it's ok. My problem here is that I'm trying to implement application warm up feature from IIS and I'm not sure what direction to go to speed up the time for first request. See http://www.iis.net/download/applicationwarmup

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely avoid using timings when starting the site from Visual Studio, you should prefer to use timings from browsing to the site independently of Visual Studio.

Also, make sure you're timing against a Release build and make sure that `<compilation debug="false">` is set in your `web.config`. Finally, make sure you haven't accidentally still got Visual Studio running or have VS "Attach to process".

The ideal scenario would be to test against a machine that that closely matches exactly what your production environment is like.

Comment: Could you, please, delete your answer so I can delete this question?I realize how stupid it is.Thanks

Comment: @gapo - I didn't think it was stupid. It's a common mistake people make and a good enough question. Hell I'll even upvote you. You even got a comment from one of the MS folks (Carlos).